# Prevent CoffeeScript from referencing undefined (misspelled) global variables

Tags: coffeescript

I'm using CoffeeScript from inside Visual Studio with Web Essentials, which provides CoffeeScript support. I just started learning the language and I wonder one thing:

Sometimes I misspell a variable name as follows:

```
dataUrl = "http://somehost/somepath/somefile.jpg"
dataUrlShort = dataurl.substr(7)
alert dataUrlShort
```

This will compile fine to

```
var dataUrl, dataUrlShort;

dataUrl = "http://somehost/somepath/somefile.jpg";

dataUrlShort = dataurl.substr(7);

alert(dataUrlShort);
```

But the result will be

```
ReferenceError: dataurl is not defined
```

This is because I misspelled dataUrl as dataurl on the following line:

```
dataUrlShort = dataurl.substr(7)
```

Now, is there a good way to prevent CoffeeScript from using misspelled variable names? In JavaScript, I use JSHint, which allows me to define allowed global variables and throws an error on unknown variable names. This way my life is much easier. Can I do the same with CoffeeScript?

Thanks,
Tommi

Comment: Compile the coffeescript and run the result through jshint.

Comment: Though `jshint` will object to perfectly valid Coffee compiled code if its options aren't carefully crafted.

Comment: Yep. By default JSHint shows many errors if I lint the compiled CoffeeScript code.

Comment: Use [JetBrains WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) rather than Visual Studio for your front end work. I have recently made the change and its support for CoffeeScript is far superior (I still use VS for my API stuff btw)

Comment: Using CoffeeLint (http://www.coffeelint.org/) and coffee-jshint (https://github.com/Clever/coffee-jshint) should do the job.